# AudioManager in android

Tags: android

this is my code.the app is crashing when i use any functions in the audioManager class.
can anyone tell me why?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final TextView tv=new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Automatic volume control.");
        setContentView(tv); 
        AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        int x=audio.getRingerMode();
        tv.setText(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a `logcat` of the error

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code I'm afraid that you don't really know what you're doing. I've decided to answer this anyway. The error is here: `tv.setText(x)`. Replace it with `tv.setText(String.valueOf(x))`. The next one is here: `setContentView(tv)`. Here you need to set Activity layout and not the `TextView` or any other widget. The third problem is here: `final TextView tv=new TextView(this)`.

Comment: yes. I have just started learning about android.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Actually, there is nothing wrong with `setContentView(tv)`, it will display your text. A layout is needed only when you want a more complex UI (which is probably _always_, but technically this is still working code). The third "problem" is invalid too: `View` constructors take a `Context` object so passing the `Activity` will work.

Comment: @Márton Molnár you're right. I just assumed that doing so has no sense.